# Laravel get top booked hotel count

Tags: mysql, laravel

Having a hotel booking application and i need to get the 4 top booked hotels.

i have a relationship, to hotel in the **Reservation.php**

```
public function hotel(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Hotel');
    }
```

I can achieve what i wanted with the following query:

```
Reservation::select(DB::raw('*, COUNT(hotel_id) as hotel_count'))->with('hotel')->groupby('hotel_id')->orderby('hotel_count', 'desc')->limit(4)->get();
```

Is there any simplified version is available to the above query?

Update: Db structure

[image]

Comment: @GopiChand, its working just fine. but i heard about withcount(), but i cant able to use it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Reservation::withCount('hotel')->orderBy('hotel_count', 'desc')->take(4)->get();
```

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: getting this error `Call to a member function getRelationExistenceCountQuery() on integer`

Comment: Changed my answer, please check again

Comment: laravel version btw?

Comment: i have added the db structure of reservation table.

Comment: missed this? `groupby('hotel_id')`

Comment: hotel id `1` is two times available in my reservation table, but the result shows `1`

Answer (score 0):

In your `Hotel.php` model

```
public function reservation()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Reservation');
}
```

In your controller you can access by

```
Hotel::withCount('reservation')->orderBy('reservation_count', 'desc')->limit(4)->get();
```